# Is it possible to ignore DNS in a PHP cURL request

Tags: php, curl, dns

I am attempting to access an API on Server 2 from Server 1 using cURL.
It takes around 15 seconds from start to finish to return the data from Server 2.
The API accepts GET information and typing the URL and parameters in to the address bar returns the data instantly. So I am happy that the API code is performant and that the issue is with the cURL request / network somewhere along the line.

Using the curl_getinfo() method I see the following:

```
[url] => http://[targetURL]
[content_type] => application/json
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 423
[request_size] => 135
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 15.137161
[namelookup_time] => 15.039278
[connect_time] => 15.057024
[pretransfer_time] => 15.057177
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 849
[speed_download] => 56
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 15.131828
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )
[primary_ip] => xxxx
[primary_port] => 80
[local_ip] => yyyy
[local_port] => 24995
[redirect_url] =>
```

It's the namelookup_time that bothers me.
Is this an attempt using DNS to resolve the domain I've specified?
Is it possible specify an IP address?
If so my host assigns a single IP to my package. Does anyone have any experience of assigning either a port number or dedicated IP to a sub-domain?
My host is 1&1 and the package is Unlimited Plus.

Many thanks in advance for any words of wisdom.
Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a repetitive query for the same name, you can either use an IP address or add an entry to the host file of the machine running the script. Unless you're specifically calling out for a DNS lookup in the script, that should drop the lookup time to almost zero.

Comment: Many thanks Rick.
I'm no expert in this field but was wondering if it sounds feasable that I could configure my host (1&1) to specify a port number for targetting the sub-domain.
So if the IP address for my hosting package is 10.20.30.40, could I somehow have 10.20.30.40:99 point to subdomain.mydomain.com ?
Lord knows if my ISP supports this but is the theory sound?

Comment: DNS has no knowledge of port unless you setup an SRV record: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/srv.html